# Android can't figure out why perference screen won't show preference textbox

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to display preference screen and with a text box and doesn't show but in another screen it has no problem? It shows a negative 1 or null.

StatsActivity

```
public class StatsActivity extends Activity {
        static final String TAG = "StatsActivity";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.stats_settings_layout);

            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.append("\n" + sharedPrefs.getString("time_usage_key", "-1"));


            TextView settingsTextViewStats = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stats_settings_text_view);
            settingsTextViewStats.setText(builder.toString());


        }

    }
```

StatsPrefsActivity

```
public class StatsPrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    static final String TAG = "StatsPrefsActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_stats); 

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this,R.xml.preferences_stats, false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Show current settings");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, StatsActivity.class));
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(StatsPrefsActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", 0);

        // Create a editor to edit the preferences:
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = s.edit();

       }
```

}

preference_stats.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="Settings"
        android:key="first_category">


        <EditTextPreference
        android:id="@+id/text_pref_box"
        android:key="time_usage_key"
        android:title="7 Day Usage"
        android:summary="A total of usage of 7 days." />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want an inital value then set one.  right now you have "-1" set as the default value.  so if the preference has never been used before your going to get "-1" as the default.  Try changing that to a blank string  "" or something if you want better presentation.

Comment: I trying to use multiple preference screens but I think since I'm calling default shared preference, its not allowed or something. I get only the build string.